# Android Studio starts fullscreen

Tags: android-studio

When I start Android Studio, it is always full screen. I do not want that and have to manually click "Exit Full Screen" every time.

How can I prevent Android Studio to start full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

**update your Android-studio version to stable 2.1.1 and your problem is solved**

change your setting only once that is,

if you change studio to full screen than it will be in full screen mode on restarting Android studio everytime

similarly,

if you exit full screen than it will retain its state on restarting Android studio everytime.

Comment: I know how to enter and exit full screen. I just want Android Studio to not *start* in full screen. Also, I am not asking for shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by now you have found your answer or uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio.

In any case,and since I had the same issue, and for the convenience of others who come across this question, the answer is to use ALT+V.

ALT+V will display the View menu and at the bottom of the menu is "Exit Full Screen".  Select that item and you will return to opening Android Studio with the menu showing and not full screen mode.